# aggregation mongoose nodejs $match doesnt work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

```
AllianceMember.aggregate([{
                $match : { ally_id : alliance._id } ,
                $lookup:
                  {
                    from: 'users',
                    localField: 'user_id',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'users'
                  }
 }]).then((members) => {});
```

So basically what I'am trying to achieve is get `members that are in alliance` then I aggregate them with `users` table. This part of code works. But now I need to filtrate `members that are in alliance` from `alliances` collection.

`AllianceMember` `_id` `user_id` `ally_id`

`Alliance` `_id` `title` `leader`

I need to show users in alliance page that have the `ally_id` equal to `alliance_id`. Without `$match` function I get all members showed up in every alliance.

The error I get with `$match: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have messed up both `$lookup` and `$match` stage. 
And also you didn't cast your `ally_id` from `String` to mongoose `ObjectId`

It should be something like

```
db.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "ally_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(alliance._id) } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "users",
    "localField": "user_id",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "users"
  }}
])
```

Comment: $lookup works fine without $match btw. So I don't think it messed up.

Comment: I can see it is  messed up in your code. And in `$match` you need to cast your id. Nothing else.